# Activate cell in Google sheet onEdit is not working when populated by Python program

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this very trivial code which works fine when I am editing the G-sheet directly from the keyboard:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DaSheet');

var lastWeightRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastWeightRow+1,1).activate();   //Move the cursor/scroll

var normalStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(10).setBold(false).build();
var attentionStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true).build();

var lastWeightRowNum = sheet.getLastRow();  // 
var row = sheet.getRange(lastWeightRowNum-1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
row.setTextStyle(normalStyle);
row = sheet.getRange(lastWeightRowNum, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
row.setTextStyle(attentionStyle);

//Move the cursor/scroll try again at the end
var firstEmptyCellString =  `A${lastWeightRowNum+1}`;
sheet.getRange(firstEmptyCellString).activate();

Logger.log('onEdit now firing!!!');
};
```

The problem is when I edit/populate the G-sheet from a (local) Python program. In that case the following statements do not work:

```
sheet.getRange(lastWeightRow+1,1).activate();
```

and

```
sheet.getRange(firstEmptyCellString).activate();
```

That the onEdit(e) function is triggered I know since the formatting commands e.g. `row.setTextStyle(attentionStyle);` are executed flawlessly.

It is only the moving of the active cursor which does not work when the sheet is populated from the Python program.

This is the starting point:

[image: Before]

This is the result after user input from the keyboard:
[image: Keyboard input]

This is the result after executing the Python program 3 times (each time populating the first empty row):
[image: Python input]
where each time the last row is highlighted according to the format in the onEdit function. As can be seen the cursor is however not moved.

To dispel any doubts that the onEdit is firing I added a logger statement in the onEdit function and executed the Python program once more:
[image: Logger]

I added the statement to the onEdit function as requested by The Master
`console.log(JSON.stringify(e))` and executed the Python program again:
[image: Gsheetwithvalue]
[image: consolelogger]

Comment: That's normal because onEdit triggers only fire on user edits

Comment: @Cooper as I wrote the 'onEdit(e) function **is** triggered'. 'It is only the moving of the active cursor which does not work when the sheet is populated from the Python program.'

Comment: @mortpiedra how many rows has your sheet? I mean in total with blanks. Then execute the python program, do you have a row extra? What i think is that you insert a new row instead of populating. That will explain the text formatting. Add some logs in the onEdit and you probably would see that the onEdit is NOT fireing when running the Pyton program.

Comment: @RemcoE33 I added a logger stmnt as you suggested -thanx! - which clearly confirms that the onEdit **does** fire based on input from the Python program (see picture I added as 'proof')

Comment: @mortpiedra well this is weird. When i test it via [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) or via NodeJs... No onEdit() is fired. I would suggest you create an doPost(e) function and deploy as webapp. Then apps script receives a post request and you can do whatever you want in the function..

Comment: @RemcoE33 I am using this logic https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Intercollegiate_Courses/Internet_of_Science_Things_(2020)/1%3A_IOST_Modules/1.6%3A_Writing_to_Google_Sheets to have the Python program write to the G-sheet, which is what you are suggesting, right?

Comment: I don't think `activate()` would work even if python was able to trigger`onEdit()` as it would be running as a different user - not as the user currently watching the user interface. However, could you show  `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))` for each of the three times. The log you currently show has a 5s difference. Maybe you edited something else during that 5s.

Comment: @TheMaster The 5s delay: 17:59:41 is the local PC time that the Python program writes/edits the Gsheet. 17:59:46 (=+5s) is the google-server time of the ```onEdit()``` execution. Questions: what does it mean 'not as the user currently watching the user interface'? Also: is there any doubt that the ```onEdit()``` function is being executed? I will provide the ```console.log(JSON.stringify(e))``` asap.

Comment: If two users use a Google sheet simultaneously and one user activates a cell, say B4, programmatically or manually,  then that won't be reflected in the other user's browser. Even if you open the sheet in  two tabs and do a edit on one tab:activating B4, I don't think it will be reflected in the other tab. Sidenote: It was unheard of that onEdit is being activated through sheets api. You are the first to make that claim.

Comment: @TheMaster I added the console.logger statement (pls see above), but I don't know what it really means.

Comment: Thanks for the logs. I don't have a answer and frankly, I don't think what you want is possible. But, why do you want this? I assume you're executing python from another terminal. So, why do you want this? Maybe I can suggest a alternative.

Comment: Seeing the logs again, this isn't onEdit trigger. This is a onChange trigger, which you installed manually through the dashboard.  Right? You named it onEdit, but it's onChange

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, absolutely correct. Now that you point that it out like that, It seems to me that I managed to fool myself believing the code was doing something which it strictly speaking was not, right? However, given that it is onChange and moving the cursor works on keyboard input, it there a way to get the onChange code to move the cursor after input from the Python program?

Comment: Nope. I don't think that's possible. It'll only work, if the change is made from a client browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me.  But it does not change the fact that onEdit will not trigger on anything but user edits.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "DaSheet") {
    e.source.toast("In");
    let lr = sh.getLastRow();
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).activate();
    var normalStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(10).setBold(false).build();
    var attentionStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(24).setBold(true).build();
    sh.getRange(lr - 1, 1, 1, sh.getMaxColumns()).setTextStyle(normalStyle);
    sh.getRange(lr, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).setTextStyle(attentionStyle);
  };
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your very valuable input. I have added an example with pictures to show what is happening and I must conclude that the onEdit is really triggered also from inputs generated by the Python program. Or am I missing something?

Comment: onEdit only fires on user edits.

Comment: Hmm so how can it be explained that the log (see last screenshots inserted above) says that the onEdit is triggered by the Python program???

Comment: @mortpiedra as mentioned by TheMaster in a comment to the question, there is a installable change trigger set to call the onEdit function.

Comment: @Rubén yes I saw that and I asked TheMaster if there is a possibility to achieve the activate cell from the ```onChange``` function instead. But since the question technically is not the same anymore, am I supposed to mark thsi question as answered, close it and open a new one for activate cell in ```onChange``` function?